# How long should I expect to wait for a simple edit to be approved?

Tags: discussion, editing, review

Two weeks ago, I proposed [a minor edit](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/249871) to fix spelling and grammar problems with an answer.  On most SE sites, that would have been reviewed within a couple of hours, but here, it's been waiting for over a fortnight.

Are the review queues being neglected?  Or is my edit so borderline that nobody can decide whether to approve, reject or further edit the answer?

Comment: My edit has now been approved - perhaps this question prompted reviewers to look at the queues!

Comment: Thanks for bringing my answer into a better shape. As a non-native english speaker, I often miss these nuances and always take such edits as an oportunity to improve my spelling and grammar.

Comment: @TobySpeight I think the answer to your question is that nobody knows how long at the moment. I have a few suggested edits in the queue here and I am waiting for more than two weeks now too. There is a [discussion on MSE about the edit queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419765/suggested-edits-take-way-too-long-to-be-reviewed-due-to-a-2017-change-to-the-top) which is quite interesting. The queue is not very long here (about 20 edits more or less), so I assume that not many >2K users are monitoring it.

Answer (score 5):

My experience with this community here is that sometimes you have to give them around a week or two to react. There are only a handful of members who actively participate in improving things like spelling, grammar or wording of a question. That's somewhat different from Stackoverflow: they have a user base which is more than 50 times of the size of ours, hence their reaction times are way shorter.

IMHO asking here on meta after two weeks about a pending edit is perfectly reasonable and as you have noted, this can help to speed things up.

Comment: It's a shame because one of the best ways to learn how to make good edit suggestions is to edit and have them approved or rejected by your peers, relatively quickly. This is important - even for native speakers - because it is not just the language correction that is important, but also changes to the domain content need to respect the community's style and rules (written and unwritten).

Answer (score -1):

It appears there's been [less than 500](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/1684255) suggested edits this year. That's less than 2 edits a day.

If there are really so few edits, I'd say it wouldn't be unreasonable to **include regularly reviewing suggested edits in moderator responsibilities**.

That should fairly trivially solve the problem of edits taking excessively long to be approved, without adding much of a burden on moderators.

(I don't know if moderators single-handedly approve edits, like with closure ... aside from the auto-approve when improving it that anyone with edit privileges can do. I don't think it would be a problem either way, but it would make it easier if they can.)

* If around 3 regular users review a handful of posts on a daily basis, that should also solve the problem, but this would be something some users need to decide to do on their own.